# IIS is changing the database username from "MyUser" to "IIS APPPOOL\MyUser"

Tags: sql-server, iis

I have an application that is written using c# on the top of ASP.NET Core 2.2 framework.

When trying to make a connection to SQL Server I get the following error.

> SqlException: Cannot open database "MyDataBase" requested by the
>   login. The login failed. Login failed for user 'IIS APPPOOL\MyUser'.

For some reason, it is adding `IIS APPPOOL\` which is making the user invalid.

How can I change it so it login in with `MyUser` instead `IIS APPPOOL\MyUser`?

Here is the connection string

```
Server=MyServerName;Database=MyDatabase;Trusted_Connection=True;security = false;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;user id=MyUser;Password=MyPassword
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Trusted_Connection=True` (equivalent to `Integrated_Security=True`) means use windows credentials. Remove that and it will use your username/password.

From the microsoft website:

> Windows authentication takes precedence over SQL Server logins. If you
>   specify both Integrated Security=true as well as a user name and
>   password, the user name and password will be ignored and Windows
>   authentication will be used.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/connection-string-syntax